# How to write unit test using phpunit when database names are fixed under yii

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, yii, phpunit

I have an application written in `Yii` with `Mysql` database having functions in which
the db statements are made using `createCommand` where the database names are hardcoded

*

```
        $params = array(
            ':userid'  =>  $this->userid,
            ':username'  =>  $this->username
        );

        try {
            $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
                      "SELECT * FROM `users`.`userdetails` " 
                            . "WHERE `userid` = :userid "
                            . "AND `username` = :username "
                            . "AND `lac` = :lac "
                    )
                    ->queryAll(true, $params);* 
           } catch (Exception ex) {
              ...
             }
```

databsename:- users
tablename:- userdetails

How do I connect to my test database in this case or is there any better way to write a `unit test` using `phpunit`...